# Android dip conversion doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, margins

I am trying to make the margins of a edittext by using this code but when I put the product of this code as a margin the area that the margin takes up is a lot less than the dip value. I know this because when I put 160 in as the DIP_Value the margin only took up part of the screen and not the whole thing. How would I fix this problem?

```
int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, DIP_Value , getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textbox = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textbox.setMargins(px, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: "when I put 160 in as the DIP_Value the margin only took up part of the screen and not the whole thing" -- it should take up one inch, not "the whole thing." Are you understanding `dip` correctly?

Comment: Isn't the whole screen 160 dip?

Comment: No. You're confusing dpi and dip. Android reference resolution is 160dpi = 160 dots per inch. So 160 dips (=density independent pixels) should measure *around* one inch. If your device's screen actually has 240 dpi, then an widget with a width of 160dip will still be *around* one inch wide, but actually occupy 240 pixels.

Comment: So dip only takes into account screen density and not actual size? If that is correct the does that mean I need different code for each size? Thanks for the quick and helpful responses.

Comment: `dip` allows you to concentrate on physical size vs. density. You may have a 1920x1080 screen on your 5" phone or a 10" tablet; if you have a widget that's 160dip square, it'll be one inch square on both devices. This helps you keep UI elements large enough for touch. You can use the same layout for all screen sizes, but you may want to have different layouts for `large` and `xlarge` screens, to provide additional information (and make them not look too sparse).

Answer (score 0):

> ...when I put 160 in as the DIP_Value the margin only took up part of
>   the screen and not the whole thing.

No, it should take up one inch, not "the whole thing."  You seem to be confusing `dpi` and `dip`. Android reference resolution is 160dpi = 160 dots per inch. So 160 `dip`s (=density independent pixels) should measure around one inch. If your device's screen actually has 240 dpi, then a widget with a width of 160dip will still be around one inch wide, but actually occupy 240 pixels.

`dip` allows you to concentrate on physical size rather than density. You may have a 1920x1080 screen on your 5" phone or a 10" tablet; if you have a widget that's 160dip square, it'll be one inch square on both devices. This helps you keep UI elements large enough for touch. You can use the same layout for all screen sizes, but you may want to have different layouts for `large` and `xlarge` screens, to provide additional information (and make them not look too sparse).